# intel AVX multiplication error in C,

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, avx

When I run a simple series of load, subtract and multiply using the AVX intrinsics I'm constantly getting the following error,

```
 Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2995==  General Protection Fault
```

from the C code,

```
double res[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            ymm0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vector_a);
            ymm1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(vector_b);
            ymm2 = _mm256_sub_pd(ymm0, ymm1);
            ymm4 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm2, ymm2);  <--- Valgrind terminated
            _mm256_store_pd((double*)res, ymm4);
}
```

can anybody please help?

currently using clang with `#include <immintrin.h>`

==== EDIT ====

For clarification, I'm loading the follwing values,

```
double vector_a[4] = {0.145000, 1.145000, 2.145000, 3.145000};
double vector_b[4] = {0.145000, 1.145000, 2.145000, 3.145000};
```

Comment: It's crashing on the store, not the multiply.

Comment: Check that `res` points a valid location in memory.

Comment: double res[4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}; <-- would this be the problem?

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: clang 3.4 on x86 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_mm256_storeu_pd`. Just like your loads, an unaligned store is required because the arrays are not guaranteed to be properly aligned for AVX.

Comment: holy...it fixed it! But..how do I align the array? does it have to be like 256bit aligned or something using posix memalign or similar?

Comment: posix memalign is what i'd use.

Comment: @lukieleetronic It's probably not worth aligning the array if its just for the output of the operation. But you'd need to either use something like memalign or allocate statically with __attribute__((aligned(32))). The later won't work with a non-static local variable.